# Populate Spinner with based on value returned from REST service

Tags: android, json, spinner

I have a REST method that returns result as "Res:"2". Now i need to populate a spinner with values 1,2. If the REST method returns the result as "Res:"3", the spinner values must be 1,2,3.

This is the code that i have implemented. But the spinner shows only 2 for the

```
Integer[] items = new Integer[]{Integer.valueOf(user2.getString("Res"))};

ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
                            cboFloorLevel.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Note: user2 is a JSONObject

Comment: I honestly see no effort in what you have tried. All you're doing is create an Integer array and fill it with one number from your json string. That's it. Why not try to add 1 and 2 to that array?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();

int item = Integer.valueOf(user2.getString("Res"));

for(int i=1; i<item+1; i++){
 numbers.add(i)
}


ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(MainActivity.this, 
android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, numbers);
cboFloorLevel.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
    int end_value = Integer.valueOf(user2.getString("Res"));
    Integer[] items = new Integer[]{end_value};
    for(int i=0;i<end_value;i++){
        items[i] = i+1;
    }

    ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
    cboFloorLevel.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: A better approach is to have a start value of 0 rather than 1, condition i<end_value and items[i]=i+1. In this way items[0] would not be empty when spinner is populated.

Answer (score 0):

Found my solution: 
You need to import Arrays from java8:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
```

and then you can convert string to int, create array and fill that array with lambda passed to Arrays.setAll():

```
int maxValue = Integer.parseInt(user2.getString("Res"));
int[] items = new int[maxValue];
Arrays.setAll(array, i -> i + 1);

ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items); 

cboFloorLevel.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand from the question that if the json response is

`{"Res:"3"}` you need to populate the spinner with `1,2,3.`

```
int item = Integer.valueOf(user2.getString("Res"));

ArrayList <Integer>items = new ArrayList<>();

for(int j=1; j < item+1 ; j++){
 items.add(j);
}

ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(MainActivity.this, 
android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
cboFloorLevel.setAdapter(adapter);
```